# Javascript alert box invoked from codebehind does not work

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need alert boxes to let the user know of successful entry or data conflicts. I've tried the following and I get no errors and no alerts.

In the Save_Click:

```
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
    (GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript: UpdateComplete(); ", true);
```

also...

```
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript",
    "<script>alert('Record Added Successfully')</script>");
```

also...

```
    Save.Attributes.Add("onclick","return ReqField1Validator()");
```

I've used GetType and TypeOf both.

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "alert", "alert('See me?');", true);
    return;
```

I've also tried the very popular suggestion

```
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");
```

and nothing works. I've tried many variations on these, moved them to the Updated method and the click method and all over and nothing ever happens.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm overlooking? Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: where you are writting these codes

Comment: Is there a pop up blocker blocking it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here buddy,

```
  string script = "alert('its working now!')";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "its working", script, true);
```

just tested it now and guarantee its working

regarsd

Comment: Another note to the OP, this will definitely suit your need.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, but I'm still getting nothing. Obviously it's some problem with my code, but I just can't figure it out. I just tried your snippet in my save_click and in the Updated methods and I get nothing at all. The Response.Redirect I have in my Updated method worked as it should, but it's like anything else is completely invisible. I changed page to UpdatePanel ID and tried that. I tried it in IE and Chrome. Still nothing. I am at a loss. I'm going to remove the UpdatePanel completely and see if that makes a difference. I hate to do that, but I've got to figure this out.

Comment: UPDATE! I tried your code in another site, and it works fine so it's definitely an issue with my site. At least I know something more now, and with one working, I can track it down so thank you! The big difference in the two pages is the one working uses an EditTemplate and has the SqlDataSource setup in the aspx page and the one that works does it all in the codebehind and does not use the templates. I'm beginning to see these templates for making things simpler are the devil.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote but please know I am grateful for your help. I'm so glad folks like you (and @MikeVarosky) take the time help people like me who are struggling.

Comment: u welcome bro, for me programmers are my best friends no matter who and where they are coz we are took the smartest way in life